# C# Retrive Desktop Background Color and Convert to a usable value(hex?)

Tags: c#, colors, background, desktop

I have the Registry key:

```
Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Colors", true);    
tmp = (string)Key.GetValue("Background");
```

I convert to a int[]:

```
char[] spaceSeparator = new char[] { ' ' };
tmpt = tmp.Split(spaceSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);
tmptINTS = Array.ConvertAll(tmpt, new Converter<string, int>(int.Parse));
a = 255;
r = tmptINTS[0];
g = tmptINTS[1];
b = tmptINTS[2];
```

Now Store in a uint[] with alpha value:

```
res = new uint[]{ 0,0,0,0 };
res[0] = Convert.ToUInt32(a);
res[1] = Convert.ToUInt32(r);
res[2] = Convert.ToUInt32(g);
res[3] = Convert.ToUInt32(b);
```

Now I am using this extern func to change the background color:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetSysColors(int cElements, int[] lpaElements, uint[] lpaRgbV);
```

Which I call thusly:

```
int[] aiElements = { 1 };
SetSysColors(1, aiElements, res); // Problem here...
```

The Problem is that after looking at this page [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.SetSysColors#)
it seems that this function only accepts colors in this format [0xAARRGGBB]
where AA is alpha RR is red and so forth(in Hex).  I have tried a myriad of different things to get the correct output, but I cannot seem to get it right. I have tried converting the data, to byte(s), but I cannot get that to work(possibly because I was doing it wrong?).  Some insight on this would be much appreciated.  I would rather not use named colors, since this is kinda messy what with all of the system color names and all(I.E Scrollbar_Color) also I really don't want to dumb this down to switch because I would like the user to pick from more than 16 colors(i know i can have more case(s), but for brevity's sake...)

**Edit:** Final Working solution for anyone with a similar issue:

```
Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Colors", true);
tmp = (string)Key.GetValue("Background");
char[] spaceSeparator = new char[] { ' ' };
tmpt = tmp.Split(spaceSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);
tmptINTS = Array.ConvertAll(tmpt, new Converter<string, int>(int.Parse));
a = 255;
r = tmptINTS[0];
g = tmptINTS[1];
b = tmptINTS[2];
byte[] res = new byte[]{ 0,0,0,0 };
int cnt = 0;
foreach (var value in tmptINTS)
   {
       byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
       res[cnt] = (Byte)value;
       cnt++;
   }
uint[] aColor = new uint[] { 0 };
Buffer.BlockCopy(res, 0, aColor, 0, 4);
```

aColor is in the Correct format now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you have two problems here:
First, you are storing color components in 32-bit `uint`s. This is not the format windows will expect. You want to use the `byte` type, which ranges from 0-255 in value.
Second, you then want to provide the color in a single uint (though I'm not familiar with the function you're importing). To do this, place your four byte values in an array `byte[4]`, then use the [Buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer?view=netframework-4.7.1) class' BlockCopy method to copy to a `uint[1]` , which should result in a uint in the format you're looking for, and already contained in the array type for the pinvoke call.

Edit: it's worth noting that you link to a different version of the function on PInvoke.net than the one you're using. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx) is the function you're trying to use in current MSDN documentation. The COLORREF structure windows will expect can be passed as the uint, still, but the format is 0x00BBGGRR - not 0xAARRGGBB

Comment: Thanks... I'll give this a try!

Comment: With a small amount of finagling, I got this approach to work. thanks! Answer Accepted.